# AsEnumerable with Where in it

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a LINQ query and need a `WHERE` clausle in it.

```
var query = DbProvider.DB.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.Accepte.HasValue).OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).Select((user, index) => new 
                {
                    user.Id,
                    user.Score,
                    index
                })
                .Where(user => user.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

if i remove `.Where(p => p.Accepte.HasValue)` it works, but the position is incorrect. Because it includes not accepted users.

When I add `.Where(p => p.Accepte.HasValue)`it returns null.

How should i use it?

Comment: If it returns null, that means there are no users where `Accepte` has a value. That's the usage of `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the last line you also could use `.FirstOrDefault(user => user.Id == Id);`

Comment: How i can use a where clausule in a query that uses AsEnumerable() most users have value in Accepte

Comment: Isn't AsEnumerable  forcing this query to return all the records in the database and then filter them  in the program?

Comment: @ChrisPitman Yes, the query look very strange, but I guest it is needed for the `index` to work.

Comment: @ChrisPitman Yes, I use the index to calculate the position of the user. His rank for a contest

Comment: @user1664803 This kind of query would have much better performance if done in SQL with a `Row_number`

Answer (score 1):

If the property `Accepte` is a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/b3h38hb0.aspx) boolean you will also need to check the value itself, by evaluating the `Value`-property, because the `HasValue`-property of a nullable type just indicates whether there is a value available or not. Its basically a check whether the value is `null` or not.

So to achive your goal use the following code:

```
var query = DbProvider.DB
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Where(p => p.Accepte.HasValue && p.Accepte.Value)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Score).Select((user, index) => new 
            {
                user.Id,
                user.Score,
                index
            })
    .FirstOrDefault(user => user.Id == Id);
```